# redirecting with virtual hosts except robots.txt

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

I'm  having a complicated seo issue where google has indexed thousands of pages from one of my nameservers. I need to redirect every request 301 EXCEPT robots.txt

This is what I have so far, but its not working. The commented out portion is a section that i originally put (that works), except it doesnt account for robots.txt. The two lines under that are my failure attempt

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
   ServerName ns2.example.com
   #RedirectMatch permanent /(.*) http://example.new/$1
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt [NC] 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.new/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone see my error? example.new is the site i want to redirect to

Comment: Why do you have Apache installed on your name server? It makes my soul hurt.

Comment: because when I installed my ruby on rails app with phusion passenger I didn't take into account when you change document root away from cpanel's default, it 'randomly' chooses a domain (its actually first one in a file), which happened to be my nameserver, and google indexed 3000+ pages of duplicate content when my nameserver started dishing up my site. now im fixing that mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone see my error? example.new is the site i want to redirect to

For starters, it looks like you need to turn on the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

---

> that worked, except now its redirecting everything as `http://example.com//whatever-page` with two `//`

This line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Needs to have the `/` removed:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.new$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is because the URI that the `RewriteRule` is matching against has a leading slash when in vhost/server config, so you don't need the slash after the hostname in your target.

Comment: that worked, except now its redirecting everything as `http://example.com//whatever-page` with two //